# stop prettier from showing output log

Tags: reactjs, prettier

Hi I'm using Prettier extension in vscode in a react project and after every save I get this message in the output terminal:

```
["INFO" - 8:45:46 PM] Formatting file:///d%3A/Yaniv%20Arad/React%20course/myapp/src/App.js
["INFO" - 8:45:46 PM] PrettierInstance:
{
   \\very long message
}


   

["INFO" - 8:45:46 PM] Formatting completed in 54ms.
```

how can I stop it?
I tried to search for a solution on google but couldn't find any